# Ruach Raah by Mayim Achronim

Tags: ruach-rah, mayim-acharonim

If one looks at the sources for Mayim achronim (Chullin 106,and SA 181) one will note that ruach raah is only mentioned in context with regards to pouring the water on the earth,but never discusses the hands having ruach raah.

The way the halacha and gemara is written it seems that there is no ruach Raah on ones hands ,but only after one washes then ruach Raah appears. Where is the ruach Raah coming from and why is it a concern only after washing the hands?